# Regex to match group of lines unless they contain a string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I can't seem to write a regex to match a group of lines delimited by two specific strings, unless a third string is present within this group.

**Example**. Given this chunk of code:

```
func foo() {
   print("foo")
   dontmatchme
}

func foo2() {
   print("foo2")
}

func foo3() {
   print("foo")
   dontmatchme
}
```

I want to only match `foo2`, because it doesn't contain the string `dontmatchme` inside the body of the function.

I'm using `func foo.*(\n|.)*?(})` to match the functions, but I can't seem to use a lookbehind correctly, to avoid matching the ones containing `dontmatchme`.

Thanks!

Comment: You might use `func foo(?:(?!dontmatchme)[\w\W])*?(})`, see https://regex101.com/r/jjbrQz/1

Answer (score 2):

You may use a negative lookahead like this:

```bash
func foo(?![^}]*dontmatchme)[^}]*}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mbyin4/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `func foo`: Match `func foo` text
- `(?![^}]*dontmatchme)`: Negative lookahead to fail the match if we have `dontmatchme` ahead of the current position before matching `}`
- `[^}]*`: Match 0 or more of any chars except `}`
- `}`: Match a `}`

Comment: You can remove the `foo` - just go from `func` to `}`

Comment: Sure but I thought OP wants to match only function named `foo`